# Help about ActionScript socket communication with .Net

Tags: .net, flash, sockets, actionscript, c#-4.0

I'm using ActionScript to connect to a C# socket server.
In the client (ActionScript), I use the following to send data:

```
var socket:Socket = new Socket("localhost", 8080);
socket.writeUTF("hello");
socket.flush();
```

In the server (C# 4.0), I use this:

```
server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8080);
server.Start();
TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadString());
```

I'm able to connect trough flash to the server. But the server doesn't receives the message ("hello") from the client. The server just ignores the message like it was not sent. But when I do reader.ReadString() again, I receive the message (so I must read twice to get each input).

I think I know the problem - this is how Flash writes the string:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/Socket.html#writeUTF()

And this is how C# reads it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.read7bitencodedint.aspx

Aditional information about how C# reads it (look at Remarks): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.write7bitencodedint.aspx

Can anybody tell me how can I make both client and server communicate using binary data?

Thanks, Moshe.

Comment: Did you miss the following in `writeUTF()` description: "Note: Data written by this method is not immediately transmitted; it is queued until the flush() method is called." ?

Comment: Ohh, In my full code I use 'socket.flush()' but I just forgot to write it here. So it isn't working even with flush.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Zippo to write a byte from flash would be:

```
socket.writeByte( byte )
```

Also here is a section of server code I wrote to handle reading the clients data.

```
        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient().GetStream();

        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        while (true)
        {
           bytesRead = 0;

           try
           {
              //blocks until a client sends a message
              bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
           }
           catch
           {
              //a socket error has occured
              break;
           }

           if (bytesRead == 0)
           {
              //the client has disconnected from the server
              break;
           }

           //message has successfully been received
           ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
           String received = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);

           for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
           {
              if (message[i] == MESSAGE_BEGIN)
              {
                 player.currentMessage = new Message();
              }
              else if (message[i] == MESSAGE_END)
              {
                 _GotMessage(player, player.currentMessage);
              }
              else if (message[i] == TYPE_BEGIN)
              {
                 player.currentString = "";
              }
              else if (message[i] == TYPE_END)
              {
                 player.currentMessage.Type = player.currentString;
              }
              else if (message[i] == STRING_PARAM_BEGIN)
              {
                 player.currentString = "";
              }
              else if (message[i] == STRING_PARAM_END)
              {
                 int val;
                 bool isInt = Int32.TryParse(player.currentString, out val);
                 if (isInt)
                 {
                    player.currentMessage.content.Add(val);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    player.currentMessage.content.Add(player.currentString);
                 }
              }
              else
              {
                 player.currentString += System.Convert.ToChar(message[i]);
              }
           }
        }
```

I included all my code just to be complete but if you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask. The server is in C#